# JS check JSON for duplicate keys prior to loading?

Tags: jquery, json, validation

Currently I'm loading a text file which contains JSON formatted data.
I want to validate this prior to parsing it.

At the moment I'm loading it using the following :

```
$.getJSON('dataFile', function(data) {
}
```

This works, but I can't validate it for duplicate keys once it's loaded as no duplicate keys now exist.

ie: if the raw data file had duplicate keys, once loaded no duplicates exist as the last duplicate overwrites the previous entry.

Is there another way to load it so I can validate the keys prior to parsing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wrote:

> JSON texts should not have duplicate keys, as per [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-4)

and therefore duplicate keys will be replaced when parsing JSON with `JSON.parse()` (which is what jQuery does behind the scenes). That means you need to check for duplicate keys before the JSON-parsing step.

I do not have a clean solution, but depending on your validation needs it might be enough:

You could basically use something like [this](https://github.com/fkei/JSON.minify/blob/master/minify.json.js) to minify your incoming JSON data (from the request) and store it in a variable, then call `JSON.parse()` on the response data, stringify and minify that as well and then compare the two for string equality. If they are not equal you could deduct that there were duplicate keys, although not which keys exactly...but as I said, if you simply want to throw an error if duplicate keys of any kind are detected, that would be enough.

```js
/*! JSON.minify()
    v0.1 (c) Kyle Simpson
    MIT License
*/
/**
 * @name minify.json.js
 * @author Kei Funagayama <kei.topaz@gmail.com
 * @overview JSON.minify
 */

/**
 * @namespace JSON
 */
(function(global){
    'use strict';

    /**
     * @function
     * @memberof JSON
     * @param {Object} Transformed data. format) json-like
     * @return {String}
     *
     * @example
     * var json = { // hoge
     *     "foo": "bar",// this is cool
     *     "bar": [
     *         "baz", "bum", "zam"   // this is cool
     *     ]
     * } // hoge
     *
     */
    var minify = function (json) {

        var tokenizer = /"|(\/\*)|(\*\/)|(\/\/)|\n|\r|\[|]/g,
            in_string = false,
            in_multiline_comment = false,
            in_singleline_comment = false,
            tmp, tmp2, new_str = [], ns = 0, from = 0, lc, rc
        ;

        tokenizer.lastIndex = 0;

        while ( tmp = tokenizer.exec(json) ) {
            lc = RegExp.leftContext;
            rc = RegExp.rightContext;
            if (!in_multiline_comment && !in_singleline_comment) {
                tmp2 = lc.substring(from);
                if (!in_string) {
                    tmp2 = tmp2.replace(/(\n|\r|\s)*/g,"");
                }
                new_str[ns++] = tmp2;
            }
            from = tokenizer.lastIndex;

            if (tmp[0] === "\"" && !in_multiline_comment && !in_singleline_comment) {
                tmp2 = lc.match(/(\\)*$/);
                if (!in_string || !tmp2 || (tmp2[0].length % 2) === 0) {    // start of string with ", or unescaped " character found to end string
                    in_string = !in_string;
                }
                from--; // include " character in next catch
                rc = json.substring(from);
            }
            else if (tmp[0] === "/*" && !in_string && !in_multiline_comment && !in_singleline_comment) {
                in_multiline_comment = true;
            }
            else if (tmp[0] === "*/" && !in_string && in_multiline_comment && !in_singleline_comment) {
                in_multiline_comment = false;
            }
            else if (tmp[0] === "//" && !in_string && !in_multiline_comment && !in_singleline_comment) {
                in_singleline_comment = true;
            }
            else if ((tmp[0] === "\n" || tmp[0] === "\r") && !in_string && !in_multiline_comment && in_singleline_comment) {
                in_singleline_comment = false;
            }
            else if (!in_multiline_comment && !in_singleline_comment && !(/\n|\r|\s/.test(tmp[0]))) {
                new_str[ns++] = tmp[0];
            }
        }
        new_str[ns++] = rc;
        return new_str.join("");
    };

    if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
        // node
        module.exports = minify;
        JSON.minify = minify;
    } else {
        // others, export global
        if (typeof global.JSON === "undefined" || !global.JSON) {
            global.JSON = {};
        }
        global.JSON.minify = minify;
    }
})(this);


$.ajax({
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
  // make sure jQuery doesn't try to be smart and parse the JSON already
  dataType: 'text'
}).done(function(data) {
  
  var raw = JSON.minify(data);
  var parsed = JSON.minify(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data)));
  
  if ( raw === parsed ) {
    console.log('No duplicate keys found');
  } else {
    console.log('Possible duplicate keys!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you then really need to go further and actually find which key is duplicate, you could run some kind of string-diff method to find the difference between `raw` and `parsed` and continue on from there.

Comment: Thanks that sounds like what I need to do... but how do I do that ?
Any pointers or links explaining how to do this ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks - I will test this now and see how I get on. Quick question, why is there a need to use JSON.minify ? what does it do ? Thanks

Comment: This does seem to work, I've got to make sure my JSON is created by PHP using `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` otherwise it reports duplicate keys when there aren't any.  Only issue I have is if the JSON is invalid.Using `$.getJSON` I can trap that,  is it possible using `JSON.stringify` ?

Comment: All sorted.. Thanks :)

Comment: Np, glad it worked. It is a rather hacky solution that would better be solved by NOT having duplicate keys if somehow possible =), plus, the JSON should of course also not be invalid, `JSON.parse()` is not very forgiving with that, e.g. will relentlessly throw an error which you can only handle with a `try/catch` block. Regarding why the minifying is needed: If your original JSON from the server has let's say a different indentation or is otherwise not formatted the same way as it will be when applying `JSON.stringify()` to the parsed JSON, the comparison would fail because of that.

Answer (score 1):

This function will return -1 if 's' is a valid JSON string with no duplicate keys. It will return an index into 's' of the problem if there are duplicate keys. And it will throw an exception if 's' is not valid JSON.

It works by doing a round-trip of parsing followed by stringifying, then it compares against the original string for any non-whitespace characters.

```
function check_json_for_dupes(s) {
    let ob = JSON.parse(s);
    let s2 = JSON.stringify(ob);
    let a = 0;
    let b = 0;
    while (a < s.length && b < s2.length) {
        if (s[a] === s2[b]) {
            a++;
            b++;
        } else if (s[a] === ' ' ||
                   s[a] === '\n' ||
                   s[a] === '\r' ||
                   s[a] === '\t' ||
                   s[a] === '\v') {
            a++;
        } else if (s2[b] === ' ' || 
                   s2[b] === '\n' || 
                   s2[b] === '\r' || 
                   s2[b] === '\t' || 
                   s2[b] === '\v') {
            b++;
        } else {
            return a;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```