# Parsing error should be thrown for a Json Payload while validating it with a Json Schema, if 2 same property name exists?

Tags: jsonschema

For e.g. if there is property called "Description" then if I validate a json payload against a json schema and put 2 times "Description", then it should throw an error.,as there are 2 fields with same key name.

The Json Schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/test1.schema.json",
  "title": "test1",
  "description": "Schema for test1",
  "additionalProperties": false,
    "definitions":{

        "link":
        {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "required": 
            [
            "customer2"
            ],
         "properties":{
            "customer2":
            {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/customer"
            }
        }   
        },

        "customer":{
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "required": 
            [
            "Code",
            "Description",
            "OrderID"
            ],
            "properties":{
                "Code": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "Description": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "OrderID": {
              "type": "string"
            }
            }   
        }
    },
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {

        "customer1":{
            "$ref": "#/definitions/link"
        },

        "chocolates": {
                  "type": "string"


        }

    }   


}
```

The Json Payload:

```
{
    "customer1": {
        "customer2": {
            "Code": 0.1,
            "Description": "a",
              "Description": "a",
            "OrderID": "a"
        }
    },
    "chocolates": "a"
}
```

The following Json payload gets validated against the Json schema, when I want it throw an error as there are 2 "Description" tags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS check JSON for duplicate keys prior to loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56924484/js-check-json-for-duplicate-keys-prior-to-loading)

Comment: Given that JSON defines this as having undefined behaviour. As such, we cannot have any means to reliably testing for that.

Comment: Hi @Relequestual, I am trying to validate a json payload against the json schema. So If I understand this right, there is no check provided by json for verifying duplicate keys right?

Comment: The behaviour in turning a JSON from string form to a language construct is likely not even to support multiple keys. This is not an issue using JSON Schema could solve. Some JSON parsers may throw an error, some may ignore the problem. It is not consistent.

Comment: @Relequestual is correct.  This is a JSON parsing issue.  JSON Schema assumes that you already have a valid JSON instance; it then further validates its content.  Schema evaluation is moot if the instance isn't valid JSON.